# Advanced content filter for Postfix using spawn service

Tags: python, filter, postfix-mta

As stated in the [Postfix Filter Readme](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html), I would like to make a filter for the spawn service, preferably in Python, which I can define in master.cf like this:

```
/etc/postfix/master.cf:
# ===================================================================
# service       type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command
#                     (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ===================================================================
localhost:10025 inet  n       n       n       -       10      spawn
    user=filter argv=/path/to/filter localhost 10026
```

So in case the mail is not bounced, it will inject the mail back to Postfix on port 10026.

An alternative to the spawn service, is running a standalone smtp daemon, for instance on port 10025. I've found [this example](https://github.com/MiroslavHoudek/postfix-filter-loop) that is using Python's smtpd.SMTPServer. That seems to be working OK, but I would prefer the spawn-method because I don't want to manage the daemon myself, like ensuring it is still running correctly.

I cannot find that much information about the Postfix spawn service and how I should implement a filter for it. What would be (the format of) the input (commands) for such a filter? Can someone provide an example, preferably in Python?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.postfix.org/spawn.8.html -- it doesn't get better than that.

http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html has some examples how spawn can be used.